# The fastest way to Recognize a shape from background in Open CV, C++

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I Have an image as background, and an image from the background with the shape in it. I want to recognize the shape as fast as possible. One of the things I tried was:

```
Mat img, img_background;
.
.
.
img = img - img_background;
```

But in some images, it didn't work. There was another way to compare all of the pixels in both images and it worked, But it was pretty slow. I want to know is there a way to recognize the shape as fast as possible? Thanks for your help.

---

And I have a question. Why the code I wrote(img = img - img_background) didn't work?

---

I could fix it with the code below:

```
   cv::absdiff(img, img_bk, img);
   Mat m = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
   m.setTo(Scalar::all(255));
   img = m - img;
```

I guess this code works. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: do you want to recognize a special shape or do you want to extract foreground (e.g. everything that's not similar to background)? ViBe is a pretty fast method for background modeling and foreground extraction, but it is patented. Subsampling (computing the foreground on a smaller image and rescale afterwards) is often a method to increase speed.

Comment: I'm trying to recognize a special shape. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "it didn't work" means?

Comment: I mean the output image was completely black.

Comment: Maybe try looking at `cv::absdiff` rather than simple subtraction. If you are getting negative results they may be thresholded to 0.